# Google Cloud Vision: Model Is Not Exporting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

Clicking any of the "Use Your Model" options does not bring up the window to store the model to a 'Bucket' as shown in the documentation. The page becomes unresponsive

This is under the Google Cloud Platform > Vision > DataSets > Test & Use tab,

[image: Google Cloud Vision]

I've tried on Chrome, Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer, and Safari

Thank you! Error log below

By using Inspect, I got the following error after clicking TF Lite:

```
m=core:49 ERROR Error: ba`InjectionToken CODE_EDITOR_EXPORTS
    at k (m=core:918)
    at wIa.get (m=core:1017)
    at $ba (m=core:48)
    at xIa.goet (m=core:1021)
    at $ba (m=core:48)
    at xIa.get (m=core:1021)
    at Ada (m=core:67)
    at Jda.get (m=core:1114)
    at Ada (m=core:67)
    at Jda.get (m=core:1114)
    at Ada (m=core:67)
    at Jda.get (m=core:1114)
    at Ada (m=core:67)
    at Jda.get (m=core:1114)
    at Oda (m=core:76)
hca @ m=core:49
Qb.handleErroor @ m=core:1030
Y3a.handleError @ m=core:3905
(anonymous) @ m=core:1355
F.invoke @ m=core:908
A.run @ m=core:897
x.runOutsideAngular @ m=core:1248
f.tick @ m=core:1355
(anonymous) @ m=core:1351
F.invoke @ mo=core:908
onInvoke @ m=core:98
F.invoke @ m=core:908
A.run @ m=core:897
x.run @ m=core:1248
next @ m=core:1351
k @ m=core:1244
f.__tryOrUnsub @ m=core:1155
f.next @ m=core:1153
f._next @ m=core:1150
f.next @ m=core:1150
f.next @ m=core:1163
Mh.emit @ m=core:1243
lfa @ m=core:97
onInvokeTask @ m=core:98
F.invokeTask @ m=core:909
A.runTask @ om=core:898
(anonymous) @ m=syaa,syab,sy5h,syae,syaf,sy9u,syad,syag,syay,sy3h,syan,syal,syah,ZnwIZ,syb3,syaj,syam,syaq,syat,sy9w,syau,syav,syaw,syb1,syai,sy9t,sy9y,sya1,syar,syb7,syb5,syb6,sya0,syba,syb4,syas,sybc,sybd,sy7a,sybb,sy9r,sybf,sybe,sybi,sybj,sybk,sybs,sy192,sy194,sya7,sybq,sya3,sya4,sybl,sy9n,sybh,sy193,sy195,sy77,sybm,sybn,sya9,sya6,sybg,sybt,sy17z,sy191,sy9q,sy17x,sy18u,sy197,sy187,sy19m,sybu,sy180,sy18h,sy18s,sy18k,sy188,sy196,sy199,sy19b,sy19n,sy19r,sy19w,osyek,syel,sy17y,sy1aj,sy18n,sy18t,sy1a1,syyf,sy18l,sy19h,sy19j,sy1e4,sy19a,sy19x,sy1e0,sy1oo,sy1om,sy19s,sy19z,sy1oe,sy9p,syd0,syem,sy18q,sy1dz,sy5g,sy18d,sy18b,sy19o,sy19p,syc2,sylo,sylp,sypx,sy18o,sy18w,sy18r,sy18v,sy18x,sy19c,sy1a0,sy1a3,sy1a2,sy1a4,sy19i,sy1ak,sy13b,sy1ok,sy1dh,sy1on,sy1of,syz1,sy1dy,sy5i,sy1ao,sy1e6,sycl,sycj,syck,syrb,syyj,sy18c,sy18p,sy19y,sy1b6,sy1ae,sy1al,sy1es,sy1og,sy1oh,sy1ol,sy1oi,sy1oj,sy1op,sy1oq,sy1oc,sy1od,sy1or,sy1ot,em2i,em2g,em2h,em2l,em8n,em8q,em8r,em8o,em8p,em8w,em8s,em8t,em8u,em8v,em8x,em8y,em8z,em90,em91,em92,em93,syac,emap,emaq,embu,embv,sy186,sy1ob,sy1os,pm_ng1_core:127
H.invokeTask @ m=core:912
H.invoke @ m=core:911
A.args.<computed> @ m=core:25
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not parse content for https://console.cloud.google.com/vision/datasets/ICN8296018091465244672;modelId=ICN4689771135208783872/code_editor.css.map: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
m=core:49 ERROR Error: ba`InjectionToken CODE_EDITOR_EXPORTS
    at k (m=ocore:918)
    at wIa.get (m=core:1017)
    at $ba (m=core:48)
    at xIa.get (m=core:1021)
    at $ba (m=core:48)
    at xIa.get (m=core:1021)
    at Ada (m=core:67)
    at Jda.get (m=core:1114)
    at Ada (m=core:67)
    at Jda.get (m=core:1114)
    at Ada (m=core:67)
    at Jda.get (m=core:1114)
    at Ada (m=core:67)
    at Jda.get (m=core:1114)
    at Oda (m=core:76)
```

Comment: Still broken. I am seeing the same behavior. Here is [a tracked issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178777280) on the problem.

Comment: @j2abro Thank you for confirming and linking. Glad I'm not crazy. 
Have a good one!

Comment: As of this morning, Feb 8, I am able to export, so things seem to be working.

Comment: Same, it worked for me yesterday. Thanks Google!

Answer (score 1):

As per @j2abro comment, this seems to be well known issue which is currently under investigation, for any further updates you can track out the appropriate [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178777280) on the vendor's site.

Feel free to edit this [Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) answer if something more needs to be shared to the community.